# Php doesn't correctly fetch querystring as _GET array on Windows 10

Tags: php, get, windows-10, query-string

I'm testing some codes from Laracasts course videos (PHP practitioner). Normally codes must fetch querystring (the part after uri) as array and input into _GET array variable. But in this case it fetches uri. Its interesting that on Linux everything is normal.

Codes are following:

index.php file

```
<?php

require 'core/bootstrap.php';

require Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri());
```

Router.php file

```
<?php

class Router
{

    protected $routes=[];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router=new static;

        require $file;

        return $router;
}

    public function define($routes)
    {
        $this->routes=$routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes))
        {
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}
```

Request.php file

```
<?php

class Request
{
    public static function uri()
    {
        return trim(
            parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'
        );
    }
}
```

index.view.php file

```
<h1>Submit your name</h1>
    <form action="names" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

add-name.php

```
<?php

die(var_dump($_GET));
```

On Windows result is:

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(6) "/names" }
```

routes.php file content:

```
$router->define([ ''=>'controllers/index.php',                 
    'about'=>'controllers/about.php',
    'about/culture'=>'controllers/about-culture.php', 
    'contact'=>'controllers/contact.php',
    'names'=>'controllers/add-name.php' ]);
```

Comment: @Pupil, its not exactly Laravel. There's just a little similarity. Because of that didn't tag as Laravel.

Comment: do `$_GET['name']` and its not related to laravel not form windows too , so remove these tags

Comment: @Karan Sadana, "Undefined index notice" occurs. As I said above on Linux it works correctly. I think this problem is caused by Windows.

Comment: _"I think this problem is caused by Windows"_ - How are you running your code? WAMP? XAMPP? IIS? I've never encountered any situation where the query string is handled differently on different OS's. I also don't see why or how it would.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the complete code, like where you actually define the route `names` and how the file `add-name.php` gets included. There's too much missing to be able to know what actually happens.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, you're right, I forgot to add, WAMPP server is running on the system. I ment saying "caused by Windows" that it encounters on  only Windows., not Linux. Of course, maybe problem is another thing, such as configuration. Router.php file content is giving above, inside the post. 
This is routes.php file content:

`$router->define([
    ''=>'controllers/index.php',
    'about'=>'controllers/about.php',
    'about/culture'=>'controllers/about-culture.php',
    'contact'=>'controllers/contact.php',
    'names'=>'controllers/add-name.php'
]);`

Comment: Please edit your question to include any additional code/info instead of in comments

Comment: Sorry, confused. Code was added to the question post.